# How to plot grid, scatter points, and trend of one graph as separate files

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am attempting to save a plot in "layers". First I want to save just the grid. Then I want to save just my scatter points. And finally I want to save just my trend line, but I can't figure out how to "turn off" my scatter points to do this. My reasoning for doing this is so that I can import each component of the graph as a layer in photoshop. 
Here's my code:

FIRST PLOT GRID ONLY

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
#ax1.plot(x,p(x), linewidth=3.0, color="#daa004")
plt.ylim(top=72)
plt.ylim(bottom=60)
plt.xlim(right=2025)
plt.xlim(left=1895)
plt.grid(axis='x', alpha=0.4)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.4)
plt.savefig('MeanAnnualFallTMAX_Grid.png', transparent=True)
```

PLOT SCATTER ONLY

```
ax1.plot(x,y,'o',markersize=3,color="#daa004",label="Annual Mean Fall Maximum Temperature")
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('MeanAnnualFallTMAX_Scatter.png', transparent=True)
```

PLOT TREND ONLY (The problem)

```
ax1.plot(x,p(x), linewidth=3.0, color="#daa004")
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('MeanAnnualFallTMAX_Trend.png', transparent=True)
```

But this prints the scatter and the trend. Is there a way to "clear" or "turn-off" the scatter points I previously plotted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you save a reference to your line you may either

- Turn the points invisible

  ```
  line, = ax1.plot(x,y,'o')
  # ...
  line.set_visible(False)
  ```
- Remove the points from the axes

  ```
  line, = ax1.plot(x,y,'o')
  # ...
  line.remove()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think for this workflow I'd at least try to save the figure as svg and open this in Inkscape. Ungrouping the results there gives access to every partof the figure.
However, it'll soon be divided into too small pieces like points or lines, but have a look - perhaps it helps.